# How nppiResizeSqrPixel_32f_C4R() works?

Tags: c++, cuda, npp

How the above function perform operation in cuda . Do we need to write CudaMalloc() or MemCopy() along with this or just a call with internally do all this.

I wrote

```
nppiResizeSqrPixel_32f_C4R(&in[0],sizeofImage,StepSize,&out[0],StepSizeOutput,DestRoi,Xfactor,YFactor,NULL,NULL,16);
```

Here 'in' is vector having input image and 'out' is an empty vector . But after executing the above function the output vector still '0' . Can you please guide me how the function resizes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It operates on device data, so you will need to use device allocations (e.g. `cudaMalloc`) and copy data to device (e.g. `cudaMemcpy`), etc.

A limited amount of documentation for npp calls is available at the [usual place](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/npp/index.html#abstract) and there are [CUDA sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#box-filter-with-npp) that demonstrate some examples of npp library call utilization.

For questions that are not addressed by those resources, you may also want to look at intel ipp documentation.  The npp routines in many cases closely mimic intel ipp functionality, so you may get some insight there.  [Here](http://scc.ustc.edu.cn/zlsc/sugon/intel/ipp/ipp_manual/IPPI/ippi_ch12/functn_ResizeSqrPixel.htm) is an example doc.

Also check the  return values of any appropriate CUDA or npp calls, and you can also run your codes with `cuda-memcheck` to get hints about what may be going wrong.